# Babashka: output valid json in a list of json file

Tags: json, clojure, pipe, babashka

I have in input a list of jsons file (let say in.jsons):

```json
{"a": "foo", "b": "bar"}
{"a": "bar", "d": "baz"}
...
```

I would like to generate a file with the same format, applying some transformation (my-awesome-fn). I would like to use babashka. My first feeling was a simple bash pipeline:

```sh
cat in.jsons | bb -i --stream script.clj > out.jsons
```

where script.clj looks like:

```clj
(require '[cheshire.core :as json])

(let  [in (json/parse-string *input* true)
       out (my-awesome-fn in)]
      (json/generate-string out))
```

What I expected to see in my out.jsons file

```json
{"aa": "faa", "bb": "bor"}
{"aa": "bii", "dd": "bla"}
...
```

What I get in my out.jsons file

```json
"{\"aa\": \"faa\", \"bb\": \"bor\"}"
"{\"aa\": \"bii\", \"dd\": \"bla\"}"
...
```

I can understand: I convert my data to a string converted again when come to standard output.

If I use generate-stream with proper io writer instead of generate-string, I get something like:

```json
{"aa": "faa", "bb": "bor"}#object[java.io.BufferedWriter 0x13e21dd4 "java.io.BufferedWriter@13e21dd4"
{"aa": "bii", "dd": "bla"}#object[java.io.BufferedWriter 0x13e21df5 "java.io.BufferedWriter@13e21df5"
...
```

I can also understand this result. I've never converted my stream object to string when coming back to bash.

But I don't how I can solve my issue. Can somebody help me please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, without `-o` Babashka prints the result of your function, which is a string. If, however, you add `-o`, it prints the result interpreted as ["lines of text"](https://book.babashka.org/#_input_and_output_flags), which is what you want here.

Hence, to fix your issue you just have to add `-o` to the options you pass to `bb`:

```
cat in.jsons | bb -i -o --stream script.clj > out.jsons
```

Comment: @Patinside you can accept my answer if it suits you ;)